# HintPath vs ReferencePath in Visual Studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio, dependencies

What exactly is the difference between the `HintPath` in a .csproj file and the `ReferencePath` in a `.csproj.user` file? We're trying to commit to a convention where dependency DLLs are in a "releases" svn repo and all projects point to a particular release. Since different developers have different folder structures, relative references won't work, so we came up with a scheme to use an environment variable pointing to the particular developer's releases folder to create an absolute reference. So after a reference is added, we manually edit the project file to change the reference to an absolute path using the environment variable.

I've noticed that this can be done with both the `HintPath` and the `ReferencePath`, but the only difference I could find between them is that `HintPath` is resolved at build-time and `ReferencePath` when the project is loaded into the IDE. I'm not really sure what the ramifications of that are though. I have noticed that VS sometimes rewrites the `.csproj.user` and I have to rewrite the `ReferencePath`, but I'm not sure what triggers that.

I've heard that it's best not to check in the `.csproj.user` file since it's user-specific, so I'd like to aim for that, but I've also heard that the `HintPath`-specified DLL isn't "guaranteed" to be loaded if the same DLL is e.g. located in the project's output directory. Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 164, accepted):

According to this MSDN blog: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/manishagarwal/2005/09/28/resolving-file-references-in-team-build-part-2/

There is a search order for assemblies when building. The search order is as follows:

- Files from the current project – indicated by ${CandidateAssemblyFiles}.
- $(ReferencePath) property that comes from .user/targets file.
- %(HintPath) metadata indicated by reference item.
- Target framework directory.
- Directories found in registry that uses AssemblyFoldersEx Registration.
- Registered assembly folders, indicated by ${AssemblyFolders}.
- $(OutputPath) or $(OutDir)
- GAC

So, if the desired assembly is found by *HintPath*, but an alternate assembly can be found using *ReferencePath*, it will prefer the *ReferencePath*'d assembly to the *HintPath*'d one.

Comment: Except they changed this in VS2019 - we've been using this setup for years now. not anymore. Repository files now have higher priority than solution build dll files - go figure :(

Comment: @Christian: What are repository files? Do you have more information on this?

Comment: @testing I'm talking about the external reference paths, you can set in your project setup of VS. Unfortunately this *crazy important* setting for project environment (we have three different environments), cannot be saved to project settings; so you have to explicitly add it as parameter to the command line compile script.

Answer (score 39):

**Look in the file Microsoft.Common.targets**

The answer to the question is in the file `Microsoft.Common.targets` for your target framework version.

For .Net Framework version 4.0 (and 4.5 !) the AssemblySearchPaths-element is defined like this:

```
    <!--
    The SearchPaths property is set to find assemblies in the following order:

        (1) Files from current project - indicated by {CandidateAssemblyFiles}
        (2) $(ReferencePath) - the reference path property, which comes from the .USER file.
        (3) The hintpath from the referenced item itself, indicated by {HintPathFromItem}.
        (4) The directory of MSBuild's "target" runtime from GetFrameworkPath.
            The "target" runtime folder is the folder of the runtime that MSBuild is a part of.
        (5) Registered assembly folders, indicated by {Registry:*,*,*}
        (6) Legacy registered assembly folders, indicated by {AssemblyFolders}
        (7) Resolve to the GAC.
        (8) Treat the reference's Include as if it were a real file name.
        (9) Look in the application's output folder (like bin\debug)
    -->
<AssemblySearchPaths Condition=" '$(AssemblySearchPaths)' == ''">
  {CandidateAssemblyFiles};
  $(ReferencePath);
  {HintPathFromItem};
  {TargetFrameworkDirectory};
  {Registry:$(FrameworkRegistryBase),$(TargetFrameworkVersion),$(AssemblyFoldersSuffix)$(AssemblyFoldersExConditions)};
  {AssemblyFolders};
  {GAC};
  {RawFileName};
  $(OutDir)
</AssemblySearchPaths>
```

For .Net Framework 3.5 the definition is the same, but the comment is wrong. The 2.0 definition is slightly different, it uses $(OutputPath) instead of $(OutDir).

On my machine I have the following versions of the file Microsoft.Common.targets:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Microsoft.Common.targets
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\Microsoft.Common.targets
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Microsoft.Common.targets
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v3.5\Microsoft.Common.targets
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets
```

This is with Visual Studio 2008, 2010 and 2013 installed on Windows 7.

The fact that the output directory is searched can be a bit frustrating (as the original poster points out) because it may hide an incorrect HintPath. The solution builds OK on your local machine, but breaks when you build on in a clean folder structure (e.g. on the build machine).

Comment: I have a similar problem, in this case, where should I place the dll files? Framework or Framework64?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45945579/where-to-place-the-dll-files-to-resolve-the-reference

Answer (score 8):

My own experience has been that it's best to stick to one of two kinds of assembly references:

- A 'local' assembly in the current build directory
- An assembly in the GAC

I've found (much like you've described) other methods to either be too easily broken or have annoying maintenance requirements.

Any assembly I don't want to GAC, has to live in the execution directory.  Any assembly that isn't or can't be in the execution directory I GAC (managed by automatic build events).

This hasn't given me any problems so far.  While I'm sure there's a situation where it won't work, the usual answer to any problem has been "oh, just GAC it!".  8 D

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 3):

Although this is an old document, but it helped me resolve the problem of 'HintPath' being ignored on another machine. It was because the referenced DLL needed to be in source control as well:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817675.aspx#tdlg_ch4_includeoutersystemassemblieswithprojects

Excerpt:

> To include and then reference an outer-system assembly
>
> 1. In Solution Explorer, right-click the project that needs to reference the assembly,,and then click Add Existing Item.
> 2. Browse to the assembly, and then click OK. The assembly is then copied into the project folder and automatically added to VSS
>    (assuming the project is already under source control).
> 3. Use the Browse button in the Add Reference dialog box to set a file reference to assembly in the project folder.

Comment: Note that in step (2) above, one can choose "Add as Link" instead of just "Add", and then the assembly is merely referenced as a link rather than copied.  This is useful if the same assembly is referenced in numerous projects.