# Silverlight unable to resolve References when switching from Debug to Release

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, f#

I am using: Silverlight Version 4.0, 100% F# solution.  I am having an issue when switching the Target Configuration from **debug** to **release**.  Everything compiles fine in debug mode, then in release I get the following:

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1360,9):
>   warning MSB3245: Could not resolve
>   this reference. Could not locate the
>   assembly
>   "System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations".
>   Check to make sure the assembly exists
>   on disk. If this reference is required
>   by your code, you may get compilation
>   errors.
>
> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1360,9):
>   warning MSB3245: Could not resolve
>   this reference. Could not locate the
>   assembly
>   "System.Windows.Controls.Data.Input".
>   Check to make sure the assembly exists
>   on disk. If this reference is required
>   by your code, you may get compilation
>   errors.

The Item group in the project file lokos like:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="FSharp.PowerPack">
      <HintPath>C:\Program Files\FSharpPowerPack-2.0.0.0\Silverlight\v3.0\FSharp.PowerPack.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="mscorlib" />
    <Reference Include="FSharp.Core">
      <HintPath>$(ProgramFiles)\Microsoft F#\Silverlight\Libraries\Client\$(SilverlightVersion)\FSharp.Core.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Net" />
    <Reference Include="System.Runtime.Serialization" />
    <Reference Include="System.Windows" />
    <Reference Include="System.Windows.Browser" />
    <Reference Include="System.Windows.Controls">
      <HintPath>bin\Debug\System.Windows.Controls.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Windows.Controls.Data">
      <HintPath>bin\Debug\System.Windows.Controls.Data.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Windows.Controls.Data.Input" />
    <Reference Include="System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit">
      <HintPath>bin\Debug\System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Windows.Controls.Input">
      <HintPath>c:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v4.0\Libraries\Client\System.Windows.Controls.Input.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Windows.Controls.Layout.Toolkit">
      <HintPath>bin\Debug\System.Windows.Controls.Layout.Toolkit.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Windows.Controls.Navigation">
      <HintPath>bin\Debug\System.Windows.Controls.Navigation.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit">
      <HintPath>bin\Debug\System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Windows.Data">
      <HintPath>bin\Debug\System.Windows.Data.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Obviuosly some Elements have HintPaths while others do not, and while some have hintpaths there appear to be absolute and relative paths...

Can anybody help me out?  Thanks in advance.

---

OK so I removed the references and then readded them and they came into the project file in the format of:

> c:\Program Files\Microsoft
>   SDKs\Silverlight\v4.0\Libraries\Client\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll

for both of the references. It all compiles - in both versions.  Any hint on th HintPaths?  How they are used and how and when they are generated? And why when I tried to modify the proj file by hand it didn't seem to matter (still didn't compile even though VS told me it reloaded)?

Thx

Comment: About the HintPaths, look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882038/hintpath-vs-referencepath-in-visual-studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you moved the project from another machine and you don't have the [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/) and the [WCF RIA Services](http://www.silverlight.net/getstarted/riaservices/) installed on your machine.

Clean your solution, close your Visual Studio and install what's missing.

Comment: Or installed in the same place?  We are working among a small group of developers and I jumped in to refactor their code, and distribute among many smaller projects.  Ugh.

Comment: Yes, it's recommendable to install everything properly and in the same place for all team members. When something is not found, Visual Studio will link it from the Debug or Release folder when the project has not been cleaned before. So things can become a pretty mess sooner or later...

Comment: When you are in a relatively large group of developers I usually avoid this issues by adding the libraries that are external to the core Silverlight set to a "LIB" folder in source control and I make sure all the references in the project point to those assemblies instead of the installed ones. This way I can even have several projects using different versions of the libraries, no matter what version I have installed in my computer or even if I don't.

Answer (score 1):

FYI, there is a bug in the shipped Microsoft.FSharp.targets that may interact with this.  You can add this line

```
    <FrameworkRegistryBase Condition="'$(TargetFrameworkIdentifier)'=='Silverlight'">Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\$(TargetFrameworkIdentifier)</FrameworkRegistryBase>
```

inside a `<PropertyGroup>` (just below the `<Tailcalls>` element is a good spot) inside Microsoft.FSharp.targets to fix it.  I don't know if this relates to your problem (it sounds like it may not), but just a heads-up in case.

(The fact that you get a `HintPath` (even if you do things right) may also be the result of a bug in the F# project system.)

One possible strategy if you need a workaround is to check in a copy of DLLs you need to reference in a fixed spot (relative to your projects) under source control, and then reference those DLLs via the 'fixed' relative paths.

Comment: Brian - do you happen to know what the plan is to fix (err release the fixes) these bugs in the project system? Thx

Comment: Since the F# project system is an integrated part of VS2010, the fixes will eventually come with VS bits (e.g. in a future service pack or in a future release of VS).