# Using different DLL's for debug and release builds

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, dll, build

Does anybody know if it is possible, and if so how to link to one set of DLL's in a debug build and a different set of DLL's in a release build on a C# Project using Visual Studio 2008?

Comment: By the way, the DLL's are not built as part of my soloution.

Comment: A little late, but google never forgets, so in this thread the question already has been answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5491253/visual-studio-2010-compiling-with-the-debug-or-release-version-of-third-party-li

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you Unload the project file (context menu of the project) and then edit it, add a condition on the itemgroup for each build configuration holding the references:

```
<ItemGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <Reference Include="Common.Logging, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=af08829b84f0328e, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
    <Reference Include="Elmah, Version=1.2.13605.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
</ItemGroup>
```

After saving your changes, you can Reload the project from the context menu of the project file.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think this can be done with default means of Visual Studio. One thing I could think of is to create some sort of "debug flag" and load the DLLs dynamically depending on that flag.

Comment: Yes, all my reading is pointing towards this being the only answer to my problem, I'll give it a go, thanks Thorsten!