# VS 2010: Set a conditional build option on dependant libraries based on custom solution configuration

Tags: visual-studio-2010, configuration, msbuild, project

I am using Visual Studio 2010. Let`s say I have three projects in a solution:

```
MainProject
DependentA
DependentB
```

`MainProject` is my start up project and `DependentA` and `DependentB` are referenced to it. The build mode is set to `Debug`. Then I create a custom solution configuration `Test` and select it.

Now Visual studio sets the build option for `DependentA` and `DependentB` to Release automatically.

What I want to accomplish is to set some condidions. For example if `Test` configuration is selected build the `DependentA` and `DependentB` in `Debug` mode. I am quite new in this area but I suppose I can set some condition in the csproj file as it is done in this question:

[Visual Studio 2010 Compiling with the Debug or Release version of third party library depending on if my project is being compiled Build or Release?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5491253/visual-studio-2010-compiling-with-the-debug-or-release-version-of-third-party-li)

Any help with some example will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you used the Build Configuration Manager to select the desired project build configurations for the Test solution configuration? It's not clear from your question whether you're looking for anything more complicated than that.