# Visual Studio and File References

Tags: c#, visual-studio

This [article on msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817675.aspx) talks about 2 types of reference, project reference and file references.

Previously I've been using project reference, but have been asked to change to file references, and structure my "build" directory in the following manner...

[image: image showing proposed directory structure for libraries]

where '4.0.0' is the version of the build, and x64 is the architecture.

***My Question:***

Using the above directory structure, would visual studio know to automatically use "debug" version when appropriate? My colleague seams to think it will, but I cant find documentation confirmingthat. i.e. Will it compile with the debug version when I'm compiling with debug configuration?

Just to be clear, I'm talking about "external" libraries, or at least libraries used by several different projects/solutions. The directory structure shown is not for the output of my application, but rather the output of common libraries that many of my applications will be using. I will still be using "project references" for namespaces/projects that are developed  mostly/solely for a single application.

Comment: See the post by @WaffleSouffle here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7284102/1660123 Looks like the best approach to me (untested).