# How Visual Studio .NET resolves assembly references?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, assemblies, reference, directory

1. The project directory.
2. The directories specified in the "ReferencePath" property,  which is
   stored in the .USER file.
3. The .NET Framework directory (see KB306149)
4. The directories specified under the following registry
   HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft.NETFramework\AssemblyFolders
   HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft.NETFramework\AssemblyFolders
   HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\7.0\AssemblyFolders
   HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\7.1\AssemblyFolders
   HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\8.0\AssemblyFolders
   HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft.NETFramework\AssemblyFoldersEx
   HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft.NETFramework\AssemblyFoldersEx
5. The HintPath.

Note: about 4.)

Future versions of Visual Studio .NET will also check : 
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft.NETFramework\AssemblyFoldersEx
HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft.NETFramework\AssemblyFoldersEx

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky(VS.100).aspx

Now I use VS 2010.

it would be great if this info was right for me,

is this the correct search order ? 
any more information about it ?
any more search path ? 
I need know exactly how VS searchs the references (the right order, all search paths, etc).

Comment: Could you elaborate on your doubts, and the reasons you hold them?

Comment: is this the correct search order ? any more search path ? I need know do exactly how VS searchs the references. sorry my english isn't not enough good

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this MSDN blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/manishagarwal/archive/2005/09/28/474769.aspx)

(taken from ajs410's answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/2733113/28411)