# csproj Reference without HintPath and without ReferencePath Assembly location

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reference, dependencies, csproj

Usually a csproj file references have either a HintPath or a ReferencePath.

I am doing maintenance on a solution that i did not create. 
in one of the project files, a reference is not resolving.
The Reference element opens and closes on itself. and both HintPath is missing and ReferencePath is missing.

```
<Reference Include="SomeCustomeNameSpace.EnvironmentSettings.Client, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=16a2c5caeea1b130d, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
```

is there a default location where this assembly might be found? or is it even valid to have a reference like this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HintPath vs ReferencePath in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882038/hintpath-vs-referencepath-in-visual-studio), see first answer which lays out the search order

Comment: @stijn I did look at that question, its not the same, as i do not have a HintPath or ReferencePath, and that question definitely does not answer my question, which is where whould the assembly be located if you have neither.

Comment: @stijn oh wait, ok I see  what you say, that answer might help me, but fundamentally the original question is different from mine.

Comment: The question is only semantically different as I can see, in essence you want to know assembly search locations. Hence the answer to the other question is also the same as to your question. It doesn't matter you don't 'have' referencePath or HintPath, actually you do, they are just empty.